# store data in a global collection in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, garbage-collection, global-variables, ram

I've a WCF which is called by a ASP.NET application every 10-15 Minutes to inform customer via email about stuff. I need the collection to recognize to which user the mail already has been sent. So if the next call is coming in i can query this collection if the mail was send before and when was the last time (i set an interval so the user doesn't get the mail every 10-15 minutes).

My question is - when i store it global does this collection expire when the call ends (collection = empty)? 
Is it enough to set this global collection in .svc class as static List or do i have to set the DataMember attribute?
How would the code look for that?

Like that?

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
      private static List<customer> lastSendUserList = new List<customer>();

      void SendMail(int customerid)
      {
           lastSendUserList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == customerid);
           .
           // proof date etc. here and send or send not
      }
}
```

Does this `lastSendUserList`stay in ram/cache until i set it to `null` (or server restart etc.) so i can query it every time the call comes in? Or does this list gets cleared by gc everytime when the call ends?

**EDIT**

So the new Code would look like this?!

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
      private static List<customer> lastSendUserList = new List<customer>();

      void SendMail(int customerid, int setInterval)
      {
           customer c;
           c = lastSendUserList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == customerid);

           if(c != null && c.lastSendDate + setInterval > DateTime.Now)
           {
                lastSendUserList.Remove(x => x.id == c.id);

                // start with sending EMAIL

                lastSendUserList.Add(new customer() { id = customerid, lastSendDate = DateTime.Now }); 
           }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you add to`lastSendUserList` it will be always available until IIS stops/restarts you worker process.

Hopefully `customer` has `LastSendDate`!!!

Also, you should trim the last so that it doesn't get too big.  So my code would look something like.

```
TimeSpan const ttl = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
lock (lastSendUserList)
{
  lastSendUserList.Remove(x => x.lastSendDate + ttl < DateTime.Now);
  if (lastSendUserList.Any(x => x.id == customerid))
     return;
}

// ... send the email

lock (lastSendUserList)
{
      customer.lastSendDate = DateTime.Now;
      lastSendUserList.Add(c);
}
```

Since you are in a WCF service, you have to be thread-safe.  That why I have a `lock` around `lastSendUserList`.

Comment: `customer` has an `id` and a `lastSendDate`. i'm querying via the `id` to get the date. check the elapsed time from this date to now and compare it to my set `interval`. if the elapsed time (in minutes) is bigger than the interval (in minutes) i send the mail and update the customers `lastSendDate`.
So that would work like in my question above?

Comment: this method gets called only once by one single aspx site at a set time - this site is called by a scheduled task (runs every 10-15mins) on the server so i guess it is thread-safe?!